# Is it allowed to place Purchase Orders for Multi-shipping in Magento 2 B2B?

Tags: magento2.4.2, multishipping, purchase-order, magento2-b2b

I have enabled **Multi-shipping**, **Purchase Order** payment method and **Approval Rules**.
Also enabled Purchase Orders at **Company** and from **B2B Features** System Config.

**Followed following docs:**

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/payment/purchase-order.html

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/sales/multishipping-settings.html

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/customers/account-dashboard-approval-rules.html

At front-end, it's working for simple checkout and can see Place Purchase Order button. But for Multi-shipping, it's not showing any option/button to place purchase orders and all orders are placed as normal orders.

Am I missing any configuration OR PO is not allowed/supported in multi-shipping out of the box for B2B ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I got the following response from Magento team:**

Unfortunately Magento out of the box **does not** support the combination of Multishipping and PurchaseOrder now.

Please find below the response from our architecture team:

> The Purchase Order module is designed to work with the default
> checkout (Magento_Checkout module), when "Magento_Multishipping" is a
> separate module that has its own logic for placing an order, which
> differs from the default checkout. The Purchase Order module does not
> have an implementation for work with multishipping.
>
> We do not support the combination of Multishipping and PurchaseOrder
> now. We will consider it for the future, but should not be considered
> as a bug.
>
> Currently, this behavior under investigation and will be released in
> future releases.